# autocomplete (external xml data) split attributes into separate fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am working on an autocomplete XML data parsing issue.

I'm trying to get each `<states>` element's attribute to be split when the user searches using the "label" as the search query.

**For example:** "Dubrovnik" is searched, and an option is picked. 
Once it is picked, the attributes within the selection they have made is split and then used to fill in the form.

**Javascript** 
Note: tjq = jQuery.noConflict();

```
tjq(function() {

    var myArr = [];

    tjq.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.thetravelosophy.co.uk/images/www.thetravelosophy.co.uk/1/js/Destinations1.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml,
        complete: setupAC,
        failure: function(data) {
        alert("XML File could not be found");
       }
     });

    function parseXml(xml)
     {
       //find every query value
       tjq(xml).find("state").each(function()
       {
         myArr.push(tjq(this).value("label","country","resort","destair"));
       });
     };

function setupAC() 
{tjq( "#country1" ).autocomplete({
  source: myArr,
  minLength: 3,

 select: function( event, ui ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        tjq('#country1').val(ui.item.label);
        this.value = ui.item.label;
            tjq('#country').val(ui.item.country);
            tjq("#country").change();
            tjq('#resort').val(ui.item.resort);
            tjq('#destair').val(ui.item.destair);       
            tjq("#destair").change();
    }
 });}
```

**The XML data is as follows:**

```
<states>
<state label="Dubrovnik Region, Croatia" country="Croatia" resort="" destair="DBV"/>
<state label="Dubrovnik Region, Croatia" country="Croatia" resort="" destair="DBV"/>
<state label="Split Region, Croatia" country="Croatia" resort="" destair="SPU"/>
<state label="Split, Croatia" country="Croatia" resort="1723" destair="SPU"/>
</states>
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ftro7bqd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because:

```
    myArr.push(tjq(this).value("label","country","resort","destair"));
```

is unable to read values from the xml data. And myArr is empty.

This might work instead of it:

```
     label = $(this).find("label").attr('value');
     country = $(this).find("country").attr('value');
     resort = $(this).find("resort").attr('value');
     destair = $(this).find("destair").attr('value'); 
     myArr.push({'label':label,'country':country,'resort':resort,'destair':destair});
```

Now myArr gets populated and autocomplete filters out the results from it.

Comment: Hi @v.coder, Thank's for the quick response. I've placed this code in for testing but it doesn't seem to pull through any results. 

Am I missing something out further down the code perhaps in the autocomplete? Thanks again.

Comment: I am not sure why it doesn't work in JSFiddle, may be something to do with the ajax call. Here is the whole code in paste bin: http://pastebin.com/PxQjMBnR

Comment: Please note I have used: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script> libraries

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I've pasted in the code you sent via pastebin but for some reason, the autocomplete doesnt the options when you type in Cyprus for example.

To view the test site i'm working on, [link](http://www.thetravelosophy.co.uk/switchview.pl?list=1) and select newtemplate, then click the "Search Holidays" button to see the form I'm working on.

Really strange!

Comment: I can see that in the console, it is pulling through the XML feed, with all the array data. It's just not populating the search fields accordingly.

Comment: Hi @v.coder, do you think you have any advice on the similar question posted [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441839/autocomplete-jquery-xml-with-categories) please?